# Rotate image in Quartz? Image is upside down! (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, rotation, quartz-graphics

- I don't want to transform the ENTIRE context.

I'm making a game with Quartz, and I'm drawing my player with lines, rects and ellipses.

And then I have diamong.png which I rendered at 0,0 in the top left of the screen.

Problem is...

It renders upside down!

How would I rotate it 180 degrees?

Here's some of my code:

```
CGImageRef diamondImage = CGImageRetain([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Diamond.png" ofType:nil]].CGImage);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 24), diamondImage);
```

If it's of any help, I'm using Landscape mode, with home button to the right. It's defined both in my .plist, and in my ViewController's

> -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation:

How would I rotate/transform it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use

```
[[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:…] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 24)];
```

? This take cares of the coordinate transforms for you.

---

If `CGContextDrawImage` must be used, transforming the entire context is the only way. You can restore to the original state using:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
// transform ...
// draw ...
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```