# How to programmatically rotate image by 90 Degrees in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, image-rotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Rotate a UIImage 90 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees)

How to programmatically rotate image by 90 Degrees in iPhone?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
//create rect
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"]];

//set point of rotation
myImageView.center = CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0);

//rotate rect
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); //rotation in radians
```

Comment: Almost perfect answer. Just that you gave rotation by 180 degrees and I wanted by 90 degrees but apart from that it is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Use `M_PI` instead of `3.14159265`, and `M_PI_2` instead of `M_PI/2`

Answer (score 5):

see this:

[Rotate image in Quartz? Image is upside down! (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578787/rotate-image-in-quartz-image-is-upside-down-iphone)

```
 myImage.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);
 myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([degreesToRadians:imageRotationFix]);
```

Answer (score 4):

this code will rotate the button..

```
UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 44)];
btn.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -4);
[btn setTitle:@"RakeshBhatt" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

same way u can rotate imageview.