# Image rotation Issues in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to rotate image (left and right rotation) with angle 90.I am using following code it rotate left with angle 360.how can i rotate my image with angle 90.

```
-(IBAction)btnLeftRotateClicked:(id)sender
{


    CATransform3D rotationTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(1.0f * M_PI, 0, 0, 1.0);

    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:rotationTransform];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 0.25f;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1; 

    [imageAdjustView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `affineTransform` if you just want to rotate the image in 2D

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);
```

Comment: Because it won't work? - the keyPath is defined (by Apple) as a CATransform3D. c.f. (incredibly hard to find, because Apple doesn't link to it from anywhere in the CAAnimation class references where it's supposed to be!) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/KVCAdditions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005299-SW6

Answer (score 0):

@M.S.B:

I think this link will help you.

[How to Rotate a UIImage 90 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees)

[How to programmatically rotate image by 90 Degrees in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581241/how-to-programmatically-rotate-image-by-90-degrees-in-iphone)

You can refer to this answer by fbrereto in the above link

What about something like:

```
static inline double radians (double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI/180;}
UIImage* rotate(UIImage* src, UIImageOrientation orientation)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(-90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    }

    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
```

**EDIT:** You can refer to answer given by Sabobin under the link [How to programmatically rotate image by 90 Degrees in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581241/how-to-programmatically-rotate-image-by-90-degrees-in-iphone). I have posted the same code so that you can refer it from here:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"]];

//set point of rotation
myImageView.center = CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0);

//rotate rect
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159265/2);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @M.S.B: I have just edited my answer to make it more simpler for you. Check the **EDIT** section of my answer. You can apply that directly I think

Comment: your edited code i use but its make only one time rotate i want every click it rotate.by the way if you have flip mirror image Horizontal code can you share with me?

Comment: @M.S.B: Can you post your code after the changes you have made?

Comment: -(IBAction)btnRightRotateClicked:(id)sender
{
    
 rotation=rotation-90;
 
 CGAffineTransform transform = 
 CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-rotation));
imageAdjustView.transform = transform;
 
 
 [UIView commitAnimations];

} i use now this for right rotation its work fine.

Comment: UIImage* rotate(UIImage* src, UIImageOrientation orientation)
in ur function i not understand its class method or instance methos .can you right sample code how to call this function?

Comment: @M.S.B: Do not use `UIImage* rotate(UIImage* src, UIImageOrientation orientation) `. Please use the code in **EDIT** section of my answer. It would be very easy to implement it. So please use that.

Answer (score 0):

A rotation of 360 degree is *no* Rotation. Guess you mean 180 = PI. Thus, 90 degree = .5*PI.

Comment: i try .5*M_PI but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some easy drop in classes that rotate a UIImage and also scale it, try looking at: http://bit.ly/w3r5t6 it is a UIImage category called WBImage