# Image rotation on button click in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Rotate a UIImage 90 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees)
>   [How to programmatically rotate image by 90 Degrees in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581241/how-to-programmatically-rotate-image-by-90-degrees-in-iphone)

I want to rotate my imageview on button clicking .Imageview must rotate in left ,right,up ,down position .I m new in iphone development so i am not familier lots of methods please help me out.

Comment: If you're not familiar with lots of methods, you should read the docs.

Comment: Try some googling first before asking question here

Answer (score 3):

```
-(IBAction)onClick:(id)sender {
  static int numRot = 0;
  yourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2 * numRot);
  ++numRot;
}
```

Comment: Thank alisoftware

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Transform function**.
e.g. -

```
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159265);
```

Comment: After Googling i find some interesting content for image rotation follow this link http://rogchap.com/2011/06/10/ios-image-manipulation-with-uigesturerecognizer-scale-move-rotate/

Comment: its really nice...better than my solution...