# Setting constraints in empty ViewController xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have an empty `ViewController`. Programatically I'm setting back ground image.

```
- (void)setBackGroundImg:(NSString*) name {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:name] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

}
```

Problem:
I'm running app in simulator. Without rotation its looks like this.[image]

But when I rotate the simulator app looks like this [image]

Any idea how can i fix this issue.I'm working on `Xcode 5` with auto layout **ON**. I see no way how to set constraints in empty `ViewController`

Comment: Pattern image will replicate itself. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe it can be done in other way.

Comment: @vokilam i wanna get rid of this repetition first

Comment: and is this possible when i rotate the simulator image also rotate it self?

Comment: what do you mean rotate itself?

Comment: @vokilam you can see in picture, image not rotating when simulator rotate

Comment: you can allow portrait orientation only in tagret settings (general tab)

Comment: It won't rotate itself, you have to programmatically rotate the image.

Comment: @PraveenM Any hint how can i?

Comment: I think `CGContextRotateCTM(CGContextRef c, CGFloat angle)` will work. Reset background after orientation change.

Comment: It will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581241/how-to-programmatically-rotate-image-by-90-degrees-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

If you want an image to rotate automatically when the device rotates, display the image inside a `UIImageView` instead of drawing the image manually. Check the docs for `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

just use 9-path, for example:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)]];
```