# Display UITababrController on leftside in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tvos

I am working on tvOS app and the requirement is to display tab bar controls on left side like in Disney+ tvos app. So can display tabbar controls on the left side or do I have to create a custom view to achieve this?

Attached is the Disney+ tvos tabbar images

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to rotate a `UITabBarController` on its side. However, you could take a `UITabView` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar) and rotate it on its side using Core Animation. To add functionality, set something as the `UITabBar`'s `delegate` to learn about changes.

As far as an actual code snippet, I typically write in Swift, but I found another Stack Overflow answer with what you're looking for.

[How to programmatically rotate image by 90 Degrees in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581241/how-to-programmatically-rotate-image-by-90-degrees-in-iphone)

Hope that helps, have a nice day!